# How to add a sum column in the last to a crosstab report for summing all measures for each row?

Tags: crystal-reports

i have made a crosstab report in crystalreport in which i have to add a 
sum column in the last which sum up all the mark of a student
 in each row.Can anybody help  which sum up all measures in the 
row ????

```
col1 col2 col3 total
 3    5    6    14
 7    8    10   25
 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to ***Cross Tab Expert***, there you could find ***Summarized Fields***. Add the row which you want to sum. Pls refer the following image

[image: Cross_Tab_Summary]
Hope this helps. Pls try and get back with your results...

Comment: Thankyou very much for your wonderful answer.I've one more doubt.I want to add a column named rank in the above report.In that i want to get the rank of each student based on the total mark.How can i do this??